# Google Apps Script: TypeError: Cannot call method of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function:

```
function myFunction(aux) {
  Logger.log(aux);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];    

  var values = aux.getValues();
  return values;
}
```

I can't do anything with "aux" because its type is "undefined".

I call the function from a Google Spreadshet, like this: =myFunction(A1)

A1 is the top-left cell of the sheet.

I am doing something wrong?

Comment: A custom function like your example is not running within an editor instance, and therefore has no "console" to send logs to. The duplicate question chain provides more info and alternatives to help.

Answer (score 0):

If aux is undefined, we need to see where you are calling this function from and how you are getting the A1 value. Also, in case you don't know, ss and sheet variables are redundant right now and serve no purpose. Maybe explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, sorry. A1 is the top-left cell of the sheet

Comment: I want to obtain the range that the user selects. Then I want to go through each value, from that range, and perfmor operation, on each one of them.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply use this and not pass in an aux parameter?

    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();